# how to copy a ftBlob with firedac arrayDML

Tags: delphi, firedac

I use Delphi Berlin.

I am trying to make a function/procedure to copy data from a FireDac query (connected to a database) to another FireDac query (connected to another database) using ArrayDML. first database is firebird and the other is MSSQL in the first care, but in another case both databases are Firebird.

So far so good and almost all datatype are working correct except ftBlob.

Here is the body of the function:

```
while not querySource.Eof do begin
  paramPosition := -1;
  Inc(mIndex);

  for i := 0 to querySource.FieldCount - 1 do begin
    Inc(paramPosition);
    // daca exista o valoare
    if querySource.FieldByName(querySource.Fields[i].FieldName).AsVariant <> Null then begin
      case querySource.Fields[i].DataType of
        ftDateTime, ftDate, ftTime, ftTimeStamp : queryInsert.Params[paramPosition].AsDateTimes[mIndex] := querySource.FieldByName(querySource.Fields[i].FieldName).AsDateTime;
        ftFloat, ftCurrency, ftBCD, ftFMTBcd    : queryInsert.Params[paramPosition].AsFloats[mIndex]    := querySource.FieldByName(querySource.Fields[i].FieldName).AsFloat;
        ftSmallint, ftInteger, ftLargeint       : queryInsert.Params[paramPosition].AsIntegers[mIndex]  := querySource.FieldByName(querySource.Fields[i].FieldName).AsInteger;
        ftString                                : queryInsert.Params[paramPosition].AsStrings[mIndex]   := querySource.FieldByName(querySource.Fields[i].FieldName).AsString;
        ftBlob, ftMemo, ftGraphic               : queryInsert.Params[paramPosition].AsBlobs[mIndex]     := querySource.FieldByName(querySource.Fields[i].FieldName).AsVariant;
      end;
    end;
  end;
```

the blob value is not copy the correct value from the source.

how to use the arrayDML in this case? any workaround?

Comment: Try to use `AsAnsiString` instead of `AsVariant`. Or call [AssignFieldValue](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/FireDAC.Stan.Param.TFDParam.AssignFieldValue) because I see no DML array benefit in your code. Or forget this all and use a ready made solution :)

Comment: I haven't used arrayDML, but I'm sure this is not the way to work with blobs. Take a look on how you need to work with blobs in the way Delphi works with them - http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Support_for_Blob_Streaming_in_FireDAC. Also take a look at TFDQuery batch sample from embarcadero http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/Tokyo/en/FireDAC.TFDQuery.Batch_Sample

Comment: @RBA, DML indexed parameter `AsBlobs` expects the same as `AsBlob`.

Comment: @Victoria - I haven't worked with DML, but using clasic datasets you can not assign from a dataset a blob value to another dataset by using dataset1.fieldbyname('field').asBlob := dataset2.fieldbyname('anotherfield').asblob, right?

Comment: @RBA, there are two different classes here, extended `TFDParam` and common `TField` (where `TField` does not have any kind of `AsBlob` property; `TFDParam` has the `AssignFieldValue` method as I said in my first comment, but it's not for DML array use).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I won't answer your question but suggest you to use the [**TFDBatchMove**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Berlin/en/FireDAC.Comp.BatchMove.TFDBatchMove) component because you are reinventing wheel here. [**TFDBatchMove**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Berlin/en/FireDAC.Comp.BatchMove.TFDBatchMove) is just for what you want to do, for moving data from one database to another (and not only that).

You simply setup the [**TFDBatchMoveSQLReader**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Berlin/en/FireDAC.Comp.BatchMove.SQL.TFDBatchMoveSQLReader) as [**Reader**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Berlin/en/FireDAC.Comp.BatchMove.TFDBatchMove.Reader) and [**Writer**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Berlin/en/FireDAC.Comp.BatchMove.TFDBatchMove.Writer), write SQL queries for both and the component will automatically map the fields by matching names. If the queries won't have matching field names, you can fine tune this by the [**Mappings**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Berlin/en/FireDAC.Comp.BatchMove.TFDBatchMove.Mappings) property. Then you just call [**Execute**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Berlin/en/FireDAC.Comp.BatchMove.TFDBatchMove.Execute).

Comment: tks for the answer. Is working fine as COPY. But I cannot make it work as AppendUpdate. Can you point me a "real and working" tutorial? So far i cannot find any to help me on this part.

Comment: What do you mean "as copy"? Do you mean that you have some problems when the [Mode](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FireDAC.Comp.BatchMove.TFDBatchMove.Mode) property is set to `dmAppendUpdate`? If so, then make sure your tables have primary key fields?

Comment: both tables are having the same PK. IDINTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY. and yes dmAppendUpdate is the problem. on the first run mode = dmAppendUpdate is working properly because the dest table is empty. but on the second run an pk violation is raised.

Comment: That should not happen. Isn't that just a handled exception that you see as a debugger dialog?

Comment: nope. also if helps see the log created by the component.*************** Start Log 12.06.2017 11:02:51 AM ***************

[FireDAC][Phys][FB]violation of PRIMARY or UNIQUE KEY constraint "INTEG_38" on table "TEMP_1"
Problematic key value is ("ID" = 1)

INSERT INTO TEMP_1
(ID, DETAILS)
VALUES (:NEW_ID, :NEW_DETAILS)

*************** End Log 12.06.2017 11:02:51 AM ***************

Comment: I don't have Delphi now, so cannot see the source, but I would expect there either `UPDATE OR INSERT` statement if DBMS supports it (Firebird supports that) or handling of the exception with checking of the exception kind for `ekUKViolated`. What you describe sounds like a bug to me. But I have no source to check :(